# Windows service not receiving some events, particularly SERVICE_CONTROL_POWEREVENT

Tags: winapi, service

tldr Why don't I receive `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC`, `PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND`, and `PBT_APMSUSPEND` as the payload to service events of type `SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT`?

I'm trying to detect when a windows device as woken back up from sleep. I have a constellation of processes that interact via IPC, which includes both UI applications with an event handler function provided to `RegisterClassEx` and services using `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerExW`.

My preference is to receive these events in a service. My understanding is that I can get `SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT` in `dwControlsAccepted`, and can then distinguish specific kinds of power event by looking at the `dwEventType` parameter, as per these docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex. However, I only ever receive `PBT_APMPOWERSTATUSCHANGE`, corresponding to fiddling with the power cord on the laptop. I expected to also receive some combination of `PBT_APMRESUMEAUTOMATIC`, `PBT_APMRESUMESUSPEND`, and `PBT_APMSUSPEND`.

When testing on the UI side, I do get `WM_POWERBROADCAST` events of any kind. Obviously I've missed some part of setup there. Again, the process that actually needs this info is a service, so I would have to IPC the event to a service if this is what ended up working.

For full credit, I also experimented with `SERVICE_CONTROL_CONTINUE` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_PAUSE` (enabled via `SERVICE_ACCEPT_PAUSE_CONTINUE`), but never receive these events at all. I had expected those to correlate with sleeping the laptop but apparently not.

Comment: There is a relevant comment on another question that itself is not a dupe of this question: ["*Services will not receive suspend/resume notifiations via SERVICE_ACCEPT_POWEREVENT on systems with "modern" standby... It seems there is no way for services to be notified of suspend/resume on such "modern" systems. See...*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28926646/service-exe-does-not-receive-power-events#comment127151723_28929096)

Comment: @RemyLebeau that's interesting, thanks. I think I'm seeing exactly that, where I'm getting "throttled" instead of "suspended" and therefore not receiving any power events. It sounds like that's just impossible to change? There is not "throttle" event? I've got some other avenues of attack that may not depend on power events that I'll pursue instead.

Comment: "*There is not "throttle" event?*" - nope